# Deep copy of a pointer to an array of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

*Edit: I originally posed this question out of context so I've reworked it. I've left as much as possible unchanged so most of your responses will still apply.*

I'm having trouble understanding how to implement a constructor which accepts a pointer to an array of pointers.

I have the following class which contains a member, `bodies`, of type `Body**` (i.e. it is a pointer to an array of pointers to body objects).

```
class Galaxy
{
private:
   int n;          // Number of bodies in galaxy.
   Body** bodies;  // Ptr to arr of ptrs to Body objects.

public:
   Galaxy();
   Galaxy(int, Body**);

   // Some other member functions.
};
```

Here is the implementation of the constructors:

```
// Default constructor. Initializes bodies to null pointer.
Galaxy::Galaxy() : bodies(NULL) {}

// Alternate constructor. Here I try to perform a deep copy of bodiesIn.
Galaxy::Galaxy(int nIn, Body** bodiesIn)
{
   n = nIn;

   // Allocate memory for an array of n pointers to Body objects.
   bodies = new Body*[n];
   // Perform deep copy.
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
      bodies[i] = new Body;
      *bodies[i] = *bodiesIn[i];
   }
}
```

Is this method sound, or is there a preferred way to construct such an object.

P.S. I realize it would be easier to code this with `std::vector`'s, however the size of the array doesn't change, and minimizing memory usage is important.

Comment: Well, yes. It may minimize the memory usage... by about 8 bytes (on 64-bit). Still thinking this is a good idea?

Comment: The memory overhead for `std::vector` is tiny. You could also consider `std::array` if you can use C++11 features.

Comment: That creates a Foo with the default constructor, and then overwrites it with the new value. Is that what you intended? To copy directly, you need `newArr[i] = new Foo(*oldArr[i]);`

Comment: Although I like vectors, I don't see how they would significantly help here.

Comment: What are you doing with the copy? Just leaking it?

Comment: Vectors would help a couple of things: no need to pass around n separately and no need to remember to delete the array when you're done (although since you need to delete the Foo s the second point isn't much of an issue).

Comment: BTW: Your function as-is is predicated on no operation but the first new expression throwing an exception, ever. Otherwise it leaks.

Comment: Perhaps the best approach would be to get a working version using `std::vector`, and then run performance tests to see if changing the data structure is worthwhile. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's lots wrong with your function:

1. Creating an object and then immediately assigning to it is inefficient, use the copy ctor instead.
2. If an exception is thrown by any new-expression but the first one or by one of the assignments, you are leaking objects.
3. Better take a `std::size_t` for the size, it's designed for it.
4. Better swap the arguments, that's more idiomatic.
5. You don't return the copy at the moment
6. Why not templatize it?

BTW: `std::unique_ptr` does not add any overhead, but provides plenty of comfort and safety.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't aware of `std::unique_ptr`!